# How should map multiple requests to the same physical server through my load balancer if the source IP is constant

Tags: session, load-balancing

In my use case, an outside application would be making multiple requests to my application for different users and I need to relay all the requests for a particular user to same physical server through my load balancer. 
Thought of using sticky session, but since the originating address would be common for all the requests not sure how should I go about it ?

Comment: What tools you are using? Windows/Linux servers?

Comment: my application runs on jboss, with linux server